# How to increase month of date format in python

Tags: python, date

I tried to set month increase by the number of month input from user. For instance, the date input from user is `date = '2017-10-06'` and frequency month is `FreqMonth=3`.

Therefore, my job is to generate date of 3 months from date `date=2017-10-06`. It would result like this: `2017-10-06` `2017-11-06` and `2018-10-06`.

I tried my like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = '2017-09-06'
datelist = date.split('-')
FreqMonth = 3

for row in range(1,FreqMonth+1):
    if row > 1:
        datelist = newDate.split('-')

    newMonth = int(datelist[1])+1
    newDate = datetime.strptime(datelist[0] + '-' + str(newMonth) + '-' + datelist[2], '%Y-%m-%d')
    newDate = newDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    print newDate
```

The output is :

```
2017-10-06
2017-11-06
2017-12-06
```

It's working just fine, however, if I change `FreqMonth=5` or something more than 3, I got the error

> ValueError: time data '2017-13-06' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DatePeriod.py", line 12, in <module>
    newDate = datetime.strptime(datelist[0] + '-' + str(newMonth) + '-' + datelist[2], '%Y-%m-%d')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
```

The result I wish it to be is:

```
2017-10-06
2017-11-06
2017-12-06
2018-01-06
2018-02-06
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [dateutil](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) extension, and more specifically `relativedelta`.

You would end up with something like:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

date = datetime.strptime('2017-09-06', '%Y-%m-%d')
FreqMonth = 5

for month in range(1,FreqMonth+1):
    newDate = date + relativedelta(months=month)
    print(newDate)
```

Comment: is there any other way beside installing new extension, I tried avoid using 3rd party extension. Thanks.

Comment: Not that I know of sorry. I believe doing it manually would be a bit more difficult due to leap years for example.

Comment: @yorah, thanks. I tried with your answer. but it comes with leading trail `00:00:00` how can I remove that. I would want only year, month, and day. Thanks.

Comment: @yorah, Thanks very much. It works great and I removed `00:00:00` with `newDate.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`. Cheer :)

Comment: Ah, I was actually writing a comment to tell you about `strftime`. Glad you found it on your own :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this... Avoid 3rd party extension

```
from calendar import monthrange
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

offset = datetime(2017, 9, 1)

for i in range(29):
    offset += timedelta(days=monthrange(offset.year, offset.month)[1])
    print(str(offset))
```

Comment: Try this code on `offset = datetime(2017, 9, 30)` I think you have an issue

Comment: @ZhekaKoval, Thanks very much :)